# How can I View RTTI in Visual Studio Debug Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project with RTTI enabled.  I have a bug were I suspect a base class is being downcasted to a derived type that it isn't.

I am aware of dyamic_cast, but I just want to see the RTTI info for a given pointer in the debug window.  The existing 'type' column in the debug windows seems to just refer to static type information rather than runtime information - if you cast A to B, it is a B in that column.